# Overload expects x arguments when attempting to export jsPDF

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

I've created a component which I'm attempting to convert into a PDF using the jsPDF package.

It uses the useRef hook to dynamically set the height and width in the component's useEffect, and the input is defined by the id set in state. It then passes this into the function call to to try and add it as an image to export.

Here's the export function:

```
const exportToPdf = () => {
        const input = document.getElementById(active)

        if (input != null) {
            html2canvas(input)
            .then((canvas) => {
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                const pdf = new jsPDF()
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', height, width)
                pdf.save(`${name}-cv.pdf`)
            })
        }
    }
```

However, in the 'addImage' call, it has the following error:

> No overload expects 4 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect
> either 1 or 8 arguments.

Looking around at other answers / issues like this, people say it's because you need to specify the height and width - but I do.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the full component for reference:

```
export const CvBuilder = () => {

    const options = ["modern", "minimal"]

    const [active, setActive] = useState("modern")
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)

    const modernTemplate = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const minimalTemplate = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

    const { name, previewPhoto, phone, email, aboutMe, twitter, linkedIn, github, skills, jobs, education, sideProjects  } = useContext(DataContext) as DataContextType

    const exportToPdf = () => {
        const input = document.getElementById(active)

        if (input != null) {
            html2canvas(input)
            .then((canvas) => {
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                const pdf = new jsPDF()
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'png', height, width)
                pdf.save(`${name}-cv.pdf`)
            })
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (modernTemplate.current !== null) {
            setHeight(modernTemplate.current.clientHeight)
            setWidth(modernTemplate.current.clientWidth)
        }

        if (minimalTemplate.current !== null) {
            setHeight(minimalTemplate.current.clientHeight)
            setWidth(minimalTemplate.current.clientWidth)
        }

        console.log(height)
        console.log(width)
        
    }, [active])

    return (
        <section className="cv-builder-section">
            <div className="cv-builder-container">
                <CvBackButton />
                <h2 className="cv-builder-heading">Your CV</h2>
                <div className="cv-select-container">
                    { options.map(x => {
                        return (
                            <CvOption content={x} handleClick={() => setActive(x)} active={active}  />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
                { active === "modern" ? <CvTemplate modernTemplate={modernTemplate} name={name} profilePicture={previewPhoto} phone={phone} email={email} aboutMe={aboutMe} twitter={twitter} linkedIn={linkedIn} github={github} skills={skills} jobs={jobs} education={education} sideProjects={sideProjects} /> : null }
                { active === "minimal" ? <CvTemplate2 minimalTemplate={minimalTemplate} name={name} profilePicture={previewPhoto} phone={phone} email={email} aboutMe={aboutMe} twitter={twitter} linkedIn={linkedIn} github={github} skills={skills} jobs={jobs} education={education} sideProjects={sideProjects} /> : null }
            </div>
        </section>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out if anyone comes to this for future reference, I needed to add x position and y position as parameters:

```
const exportToPdf = () => {
        const input = document.getElementById(active)

        if (input != null) {
            html2canvas(input)
            .then((canvas) => {
                const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                const pdf = new jsPDF()
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, height, width)
                pdf.save(`${name}-cv.pdf`)
            })
        }
    }
```